# All dropdowns (two per list row) inherit the values on change of the two dropdowns in the first list row

Tags: jquery

I have a list of orders which contains among others two dropdowns with the following classes

"labostaffs"

"statusorder"

List rows are called "order".

Inside the order, we can have, depending the product, several other rows.

In each order we can find the same two dropdowns, but depending the product, they are not always in the same row.

I would like when the value of those two dropdowns changes in the first list row (order), the value of all the dropdowns in the other list rows (order) inherit the values :

All "labostaffs" dropdowns starting list row (order) 2 inherit the value of the "labostaffs" dropdown of list row (order) 1

All "statusorder" dropdowns starting list row (order) 2 inherit the value of the "statusorder" dropdown of list row (order) 1

I can now change the value of all "statusorder" dropdowns of the array, when I'm selecting a value into the first "dropdownlabostaffs" dropdown.

I just don't know how to populate, starting the second order (list row), the  "dropdownlabostaffs" dropdowns with the value of the first "dropdownlabostaffs" dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdownlabostaffs').on('change', function() {

    if (this.value != '') {

      $('.statusorder').prop('selectedIndex', 3);

    } else if (this.value == '') {

      $('.statusorder').prop('selectedIndex', 2);

    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order">

  <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="1008">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 takecareof">
      <h5>Prise en charge par</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="dropdownlabostaffs" class="dropdownlabostaffs form-control">
          <option value="">Artisans</option>
          <option value="3">Labo Patissier Un Test</option>
          <option value="24">Labo Patissier Deux Test</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ordernr">
      <h5>Commande no</h5>
      <p>1008</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 orderby">
      <h5>Commandé par</h5>
      <p>Client Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 forcustomer">
      <h5>Pour Client</h5>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 laboratory">
      <h5>Laboratoire</h5>
      <p>Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 status">
      <h5>Statut</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="statusorder" class="statusorder form-control">
          <option value="">Status</option>
          <option value="1">Annulée</option>
          <option value="2" selected="">Non traitée</option>
          <option value="3">En traitement</option>
          <option value="4">Traitement achevé</option>
          <option value="5">Achevée</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pickup">
      <h5>Date | heure de retrait</h5>
      <p>30-06-2019 | 13:15</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 category">
      <h5>Catégorie</h5>
      <p>Pain-surprise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 product">
      <h5>Produit</h5>
      <p>Mélangé</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 weight">
      <h5>Poids</h5>
      <p>2.5 Kg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 colorribbon">
      <h5>Couleur Ruban</h5>
      <p>Blanc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 variante1">
      <h5>Assortiment 1</h5>
      <p>Confiture Fraise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante2">
      <h5>Assortiment 2</h5>
      <p>Foie gras</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante3">
      <h5>Assortiment 3</h5>
      <p>Gruyère</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante4">
      <h5>Assortiment 4</h5>
      <p>Jambon</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="order">

  <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="1008">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 takecareof">
      <h5>Prise en charge par</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="labostaffs" class="labostaffs form-control">
          <option value="">Artisans</option>
          <option value="3">Labo Patissier Un Test</option>
          <option value="24">Labo Patissier Deux Test</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ordernr">
      <h5>Commande no</h5>
      <p>1009</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 orderby">
      <h5>Commandé par</h5>
      <p>Client Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 forcustomer">
      <h5>Pour Client</h5>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 laboratory">
      <h5>Laboratoire</h5>
      <p>Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 status">
      <h5>Statut</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="statusorder" class="statusorder form-control">
          <option value="">Status</option>
          <option value="1">Annulée</option>
          <option value="2" selected="">Non traitée</option>
          <option value="3">En traitement</option>
          <option value="4">Traitement achevé</option>
          <option value="5">Achevée</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pickup">
      <h5>Date | heure de retrait</h5>
      <p>30-07-2019 | 13:15</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 category">
      <h5>Catégorie</h5>
      <p>Pain-surprise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 product">
      <h5>Produit</h5>
      <p>Mélangé</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 weight">
      <h5>Poids</h5>
      <p>2.5 Kg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 colorribbon">
      <h5>Couleur Ruban</h5>
      <p>Blanc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 variante1">
      <h5>Assortiment 1</h5>
      <p>Confiture Fraise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante2">
      <h5>Assortiment 2</h5>
      <p>Foie gras</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante3">
      <h5>Assortiment 3</h5>
      <p>Gruyère</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante4">
      <h5>Assortiment 4</h5>
      <p>Jambon</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="order">

  <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="1008">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 takecareof">
      <h5>Prise en charge par</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="labostaffs" class="labostaffsform-control">
          <option value="">Artisans</option>
          <option value="3">Labo Patissier Un Test</option>
          <option value="24">Labo Patissier Deux Test</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ordernr">
      <h5>Commande no</h5>
      <p>1010</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 orderby">
      <h5>Commandé par</h5>
      <p>Client Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 forcustomer">
      <h5>Pour Client</h5>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 laboratory">
      <h5>Laboratoire</h5>
      <p>Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 status">
      <h5>Statut</h5>
      <p>
        <select name="statusorder" class="statusorderform-control">
          <option value="">Status</option>
          <option value="1">Annulée</option>
          <option value="2" selected="">Non traitée</option>
          <option value="3">En traitement</option>
          <option value="4">Traitement achevé</option>
          <option value="5">Achevée</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pickup">
      <h5>Date | heure de retrait</h5>
      <p>30-07-2019 | 13:15</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 category">
      <h5>Catégorie</h5>
      <p>Pain-surprise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 product">
      <h5>Produit</h5>
      <p>Mélangé</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 weight">
      <h5>Poids</h5>
      <p>2.5 Kg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 colorribbon">
      <h5>Couleur Ruban</h5>
      <p>Blanc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 variante1">
      <h5>Assortiment 1</h5>
      <p>Confiture Fraise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante2">
      <h5>Assortiment 2</h5>
      <p>Foie gras</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante3">
      <h5>Assortiment 3</h5>
      <p>Gruyère</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 variante4">
      <h5>Assortiment 4</h5>
      <p>Jambon</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're repeating multiple `id` attributes several times which is invalid. If you want to group elements together use common classes, as `id` must be unique within the DOM

Comment: @rory-mccrossan now it should be correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Solution found with help of @heretic-monkey :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dropdownlabostaffs:first').on('change', function() {

        if(this.value != '') {

            var isReadOnly = $('.dropdownlabostaffs, .statusorder');
            var domElements = $('.dropdownlabostaffs, .statusorder');

            $(domElements).not(":first").prop('readonly', isReadOnly);
            $(domElements).not(":first").toggleClass('.dropdownlabostaffs', isReadOnly);
            $(domElements).not(":first").find('option').prop('hidden', isReadOnly);

            var labostaffs_new = $('.dropdownlabostaffs').val();
            console.log('new_labostaffs :'+labostaffs_new);

            $('.dropdownlabostaffs').not(':first').val(labostaffs_new);
            $('.statusorder').prop('selectedIndex',3);

        }

        else if(this.value == '') {

            $('.statusorder').prop('selectedIndex',2);

        }

    })

})
```

Comment: Note that `labostaffs_new` will always be the value of the first `select` with that class. That appears to be what you want, but your event will also fire when any of the `select`s with that class in rows 2+ are changed. You may want to consider using `$('.dropdownlabostaffs:first').on('change', ...` Also, the line of code with `option[value=` in it is unnecessary, since the `change` event will not be raised unless the option with that value is already selected. (Also, you should use `prop("selected", true)` to set the `selected` property).

Comment: @heretic-monkey Many thanks for your time, explanations and corrections, it is appreciated : all '.dropdownlabostaffs' and '.statusorder' will be readonly except '.dropdownlabostaffs:first'. 

If I delete the following line $('.dropdownlabostaffs option[value="' + labostaffs_new +'"]').not(":first").attr('selected', 'selected'); with $('.dropdownlabostaffs option[value="' + labostaffs_new +'"]').not(":first").attr('selected', 'selected'); then the value of all '.dropdownlabostaffs' (expect the first) are not changed !?

Comment: Ah, yes. You may want to consider using `$('.dropdownlabostaffs').val(labostaffs_new);` in that case.

Comment: @heretic-monkey Great tips, thanks a lot, learned a few thing which are helpfull. Appreciated, cheers